# How to pick an Ubuntu netbook?

Tags: hardware

I will soon need to buy a new netbook and I'd like it to be fully supported by latest Ubuntu. I know of [Ubuntu certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/), but its navigation is terrible - for example, I cannot filter by screen size or weight, which are one of biggest factors for me. Which sources should I look at when looking for an Ubuntu supported laptop of a specific kind?

Comment: I hope you find an answer, however, I feel like you may need to go the other way with it.  Knowing there are a few hundred certified laptops, I would find a few laptops not knowing which are certified, and then check against the certified list.  Not the answer you're looking for, but might be your only option.